# c# embed all localized resources inside class library project output

Tags: asp.net, resources

I am working on a class library project which is meant to be used by an asp.net app. I need to include both my resources (default and english) in my class library project dll and pass it to the asp.net app. At the moment only the default resource file is embeded in the project dll and this has as a result the asp.net app always to get the default language.

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: when I build my class library project I want only one dll as output and not one dll which contains main code and default language and one dll with the localized resources